# How to set language for Google Place Details result in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to set the language in which the results of Google Places API will be presented. I want the result I could get using this url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=A_PLACE_ID&key=MY_EY&language=el
```

In android I get place details like this:

```
PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeID);
placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
```

I cannot find a way to set language for the results like above with "language=el".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't set language on the Places API for Android. The best way to go with this is to call the [Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) API. The resource has an optional `language` parameter to indicate the language of the response.

More information are shown here for the [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).