# How to set text of google api's dialog in application's default language

Tags: android, google-api, locale, google-places-api, google-signin

I have set my application's default language in hindi(i.e. other than system default language) and using google's api (PlaceAutocomplete, GoogleSignIn).

Both are showing text in english(system default language), rather than in hindi or whatever the application's default language.

Is there any way, I can force them to load in application's default language or I can pass my default application's language.

Thanks. It would be really helpful. Looking for any update.

Comment: Looks like this may not be possible with the native API, currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321356/how-to-set-language-for-google-place-details-result-in-android

Answer (score -1):

you can't set system default language.If you want to give multiple language.Then from   **Locale** you can set the language.By default its english if you changed then make it your like this.Please check below code.

Selection of the language and save value of language in **SharedPreferences**.After whenever start app check the value of language preferences then make it selection their.

Make sure every strings should be add in the value folder in the form of this.

For default english then put all strings inside **values**.For hindi you need to set **values-hi**.Same thing happen for other language put their string with country code.For country code go from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Common.MYPREFERENCE_LANGUAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if (parent.getSelectedItem().equals("English")) {
                Utils.updateLanguage(activity, "en");
                editor.putString("language", "en");

            } else {
                Utils.updateLanguage(activity, "hi");
                editor.putString("language", "hi");
            }
            editor.apply();
```

public static void updateLanguage(Context context,String lang) {

```
    String mlanguage = getlanguage(lang);
    PurplkiteLogs.logError("", " language update " + mlanguage);
    Locale locale = null;
    Configuration config;

    try {
        if (mlanguage.equals("en")) {
            locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        } else if (mlanguage.equals("hi")) {
             locale = setLocale(context,"hi");

        } else {
            locale = new Locale(mlanguage);
        }

        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        mlanguage = null;
        config = null;
        locale = null;
        context = null;
    }
}

private static String getlanguage(String lang) {
    String mlang = null;
    if (lang != null) {
        if (lang.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
            mlang = "hi";
        } else {
            mlang = "en";
        }
    }
    return mlang;
}

public static Locale setLocale(Context context ,String lang ) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    return conf.locale;
}
```

Thanks, Hope this will help you to solve your problem and clearing your concept.

Comment: You didn't get my question clearly. I have already done these. Need to know , how to make these google api localised based on my app language.