# Android - Google Places API auto complete sdk, How get results in only English?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Maps Places autocomplete SDK in my app. Instead of using the default fragment implementation I am using a custom autocomplete implementation. It works fine, but the issue is that I'm getting search results in regional languages. For example when i search Mumbai, the results I'm getting is in Hindi. How can I change default language to English.?

Comment: Apparently It cannot be changed but there is an alternative `Place Details`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321356/how-to-set-language-for-google-place-details-result-in-android

Comment: Have a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150.

Answer (score 2):

The `Places.initialize(Context, API_Key, Locale)` call that you probably have on your `Application` class has a third parameter to set the results locale, where you could for example write `Locale.US` to have them all in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your request like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&key=YOUR_KEY&language=en&latlng=19.075983,72.877655&result_type=route|premise|locality|establishment|neighborhood

Pass your language like "en" for English